# Number of Employees at a particular Branch overtime

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to count the number of employees at a certain branch over different periods of time. I am providing a sample below.
I have an employee table:
[image]

A date table:

[image]

I have used the formula below to count the number of employees at the "Doe" branch at certain periods of time. I have created inactive relationships between the two tables. I am using the "Year" and "QTR" columns from the date column as filters.

Number of Employees =
CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(tEmployee),
FILTER(VALUES(tEmployee[Enter Date]),tEmployee[Enter Date] <= MAX(tDates[Dates])),
FILTER(VALUES(tEmployee[Leave Date]), OR(tEmployee[Leave Date] >= MIN(tDates[Dates]),ISBLANK(tEmployee[Leave Date]))))

However, my numbers seems to add up/mess up over the two years which is something I am trying to avoid. Like here for example, my number of employees shows 4 for the year 2019 Q1:

[image]

Whereas, I have only had one employee in the  branch during that time.

[image]

I am trying to make this as dynamic as possible. However, I guess I am having trouble trying to figure out what I am doing wrong here. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How can someone leave before they enter?

Comment: Those should be 2020. I was kind of in a haste while creating the samples.